# Richedit 2.0 Undo after WM_SETTEXT

Tags: winapi, undo, richedit

We use Richedit 2.0 for our script editor, which has automatic multi-level undo and redo for when you type. When we want to build our script or when the script opens, I reformat the text and send it to the rich edit control by WM_SETTEXT. This clears the undo buffer.

How can I get it so that after reformatting my script I can still press CTRL-Z and it will go back to the previous text, and previous undos before that, before I did the reformat ? I don't know how richedit saves the undos, but all it would seem to need is a way of not clearing the undo buffer when I do the WM_SETTEXT, and storing an undo point before I do that. Is this possible ?

Thanks

Shaun Southern

Answer (score 3):

Use [`EM_REPLACESEL`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb761633(v=vs.85).aspx) and `WPARAM` set to `TRUE` to enable undo option. Example:

```
//select the whole range to simulate `WM_SETTEXT`
SendMessage(handle, EM_SETSEL, (WPARAM)0, (LPARAM)-1);

//replace text
SendMessage(handle, EM_REPLACESEL, TRUE, (WPARAM)L"Text");
```